# Geometrical representation of $n^n$

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus

How can we represent geometrically $$n^n,\quad n \in \mathbb{N}$$

For example if $n = 1 \longrightarrow$ a line segment of unit length, $n = 2\longrightarrow$ a square of side $2$ unit's......

Regards,
vishal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$n^n$ can be thought of as the volume of a hypercube, with each dimension being length $n$, with $n$ dimensions.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercube

Comment: how many unit hypercube's are there in $$n^n hypercube?$$

Comment: @vishal $n^n$ unit hypercubes. $(\frac{n^n}{1})$, one unit of each $n$ will results in $n$ units per dimension, with $n$ dimensions gives $n^n$

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say, "with each _side_ being length $n$"?

Comment: Sure. I was talking about how many units there were per side length @limitless